# Quick way to get full directory size

Tags: filesystems, size, du

My app need to get total directory size as quick as possible. Standart `du` command works slow for big directories. Possible solution with Linux `inotify` doesn't work with NFS. So I end up with these variants:

- tracking file changes in app(very hard)
- run `du` command once a day to collect data for app
- a simple indexer(with `inotify`-like functionality to detect changes instantly)

Last way seems to be a solution, but I did not found such software. It should work the way dropbox client does. I don't know how `dropbox` catches changes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I would keep a record of the directories (each node in the tree) and only if they have been touched (find out using its last write access time) I would redo the `du` once a day (or what seems feasible in your case).

Of course, this would only find changes due to creation and removal of files (or renamings, but that's not so relevant I guess).  If you have file size changes without creating new files, this will not work properly.  But in most use cases this approach could work quite well.